# Python multithread using queue - the program gets blocked forever

Tags: python, multithreading, queue, block

I am not sure which part of my program is wrong. It will be blocked at the join() calls of two queues. However, if I removed the 2 join calls, the program does not work at all.

```
    import threading
    import Queue

    queue = Queue.Queue()
    out_queue = Queue.Queue()

    fruits = ['apple', 'strawberry', 'banana', 'peach', 'rockmelon']

    class WorkerThread(threading.Thread):
        def __init__(self, queue, out_queue):
            threading.Thread.__init__(self)
            self.queue = queue
            self.out_queue = out_queue
        def run(self):
            print 'run'
            while not self.queue.empty():
                name = self.queue.get()
                self.out_queue.put(name)
                self.queue.task_done()

    def main():
        print 'start'
        for i in xrange(5):
            t = WorkerThread(queue, out_queue)
            t.setDaemon(True)
            t.start()
        #populate the queue
        for fruit in fruits:
            queue.put(fruit)
        queue.join()
        out_queue.join()
        while not out_queue.empty():
            print out_queue.get()
        print 'end'

    if __name__=='__main__':
        main()
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just noticed something... are you trying to simulate adding more items to `queue` while the workers are still running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `out_queue.join()`, which waits until `out_queue.task_done()` has been called the same number of times `out_queue.put()` has been called. However, you're never calling `out_queue.task_done()`. This can best be fixed by never calling `out_queue.join()` in the first place.

EDIT: also, you are populating `queue` after you start your `WorkerThread`s. This means there's a chance that the worker threads will run and finish before you've had a chance to insert all your elements. Inserting them before starting the worker thread will fix this.

Comment: But there is one more problem, is that sometimes it works and prints all fruits, but sometimes it doesn't and is still blocked as if I added the out_queue.join().